# I want to print the even numbers first and then the odd numbers

Tags: assembly, emu8086

```
DOS segment
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
array1 dw 1,4,6,3,7   ; since division 8 bit divisor require 16 bit dividend
.code
 main proc
 mov ax,@data
 mov ds,ax
 lea si,array1   
 mov cx,5
 l1:   
 mov ax,[si] 
 mov bl,2
 div bl
 cmp ah,0
 jne odd           **if the remainder is not 0 means even**

 resume:   
 inc si   
 loop l1   

 odd:
 push ax                       **I am using stack**
 jmp resume

 mov cx,5
 l2:   
 mov ax,[si] 
 mov bl,2
 div bl
 cmp ah,0
 je even            **if the remainder is 0 means even**

 re:   
 inc si   
 loop l2   

 even:
 push ax
 jmp re

 mov cx,5
 l3:
 pop dx 
 mov ah,2
 int 21h
 loop l3
 main endp
end main
```

I believe my algorithm is correct but the issue I am facing is divide error. I looked around and it occurs when `CX=0` but then how will the loop work? I am confused.

I would appreciate anyone telling me the solution

Comment: I specified mov cx,4 but why my loop not stopping at 4

Comment: What are you trying to do with `jmp resume`?  Cuz it looks like that sends you right back into the loop.

Comment: I shouldn't? I thought I must since when it jumps to label it goes out loop so I thought maybe I have to bring it back  for next iteration

Comment: i tried to run it without jmp but the loop only iterated once if I do life before goes infinite what should I do

Comment: Read the code.  If it only executes once, how could it have gotten out of the loop?  Since there's only 1 other jump instruction (`je l2`) that must be where it's happening.  So if ah=0 after performing the division, it's going to jump over the loop instruction and away we go.  Why might ah be zero?  Time to use a debugger.  In particular, look to see what happens with `lea ax,[si]`.

Comment: It's not at all what the intended behaviour of this code is

Comment: can you please explain more

Answer (score 0):

> ...if the remainder is not 0 means even
>   ...if the remainder is 0 means even

It can't be that both are correct at the same time!

### The first loop pushes the odd numbers

> ```
> lea si,array1   
> mov cx,5
> l1:   
> mov ax,[si] 
> mov bl,2
> div bl
> cmp ah,0
> jne odd           **if the remainder is not 0 means even**
> resume:   
> inc si   
> loop l1   
> odd:
> push ax                       **I am using stack**
> jmp resume
> ```

The problem is that you've placed the *odd* label right below the `LOOP` instruction that finishes the loop (when `CX` becomes 0). The code will erroneously fall through in these `push ax` and `jmp resume` instructions!
You need to reorganize the code by-passing that `push ax`:

```
cmp  ah, 0
je   Even
push ax     ; This pushes an ODD number BUT DOES IT ? (1)
Even:
inc  si     ; This advances to the next number BUT DOES IT ? (2)
loop l1
```

(1) The `AX` register does no longer hold the number from the array and so you need to push the word from the array using `push word ptr [si]`.
(2) Because the array contains **words** you need to advance by 2 with `add si, 2`.

### The second loop pushes the even numbers

> ```
> mov cx,5
> l2:   
> mov ax,[si] 
> mov bl,2
> div bl
> cmp ah,0
> je even            **if the remainder is 0 means even**
> re:   
> inc si   
> loop l2   
> even:
> push ax
> jmp re
> ```

Everything that I said for the first loop applies here also. Additionally you need to initialize the `SI` register with `lea si, array1`.

### The third loop prints everything that was pushed

```
mov cx,5
l3:
pop dx 
mov ah,2
int 21h
loop l3
```

What you pop off the stack is a **number** but the DOS.Printchar function expects a **character** in `DL`. A little conversion is needed:

```
pop  dx
add  dl, '0'
```

---

Some of the problems in your program stem from the fact that you used a division by 2 to test for even/odd. This made you define the array as words and you forgot to change the `inc si` instruction.
The way to see if a number is even or odd is by looking at its lowest bit. You can use the `test` instruction for it:

```
array1 DB 1, 4, 6, 3, 7
...
L1:
mov  al, [si]
test al, 1
jz   Even
push ax       ; Pushing the odd number still in the AL register
Even:
inc  si
dec  cx
jnz  L1
```